# Regex google analytics - Filter directories and languages from url

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a new Google Analytics view filter to show frontpage,  show localized pages and some directories. This is currently my regex.

```
^\/$|^\/fr|^\/page|)(\/\w*)*
```

Pages I want to show for example

```
/
/page 
/page/
/page/elephant
/fr
/fr/123
/fr/test
/fr/test/gold
```

Pages I do NOT want to show

```
/frant
/franythingafter
/fr-13212
/page1231
/page-28
/fr21
```

I can't find myself how to restrict the cases shown above like contains other text after *fr*.

Advice is welcome?

Comment: Try [`^/(fr|page)?(/(\d*|test)?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/z7SCTl/1).

Comment: You don't give enough information in the want/do not want examples. Like `/` and nothing else other than `(page|fr)` ? Then what happens after page/fr ... nothing or digit or test ? Be a little more specific.

Comment: @sln I updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is missing a few things. You could update it to add an opening parenthesis `(` for the alternation,  assert the end of the line `$` and remove the third pipe `|` in the alternative:

[`^(\/$|^\/fr|^\/page)(\/\w*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/3LY87X/1)

You might also write it using an optional alternation `(?:fr|page)?` followed by an optional part which matches a forward slash `/` followed by zero or more whitespace characters `(\/(\w*)?)?`

[`^\/(fr|page)?(\/(\w*)?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/6XghHG/1)